# rospy.wait_for_message just hangs

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there is no exception or anything, `rospy.wait_for_message` just hangs, and no result is returned, and no subsequent code is executed. running

```
rostopic echo /my_topic
```

is able to yield result. Someone can provide an example of how to use wait_fo_message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299915/rospy.wait_for_message-just-hangs/) by [Marc_Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35874/marc_chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-08-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#wait_for_message). Or, if you look at the [source for the `wait_for_message` function](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/e96c407c64e1c17b0dd2bb85b67f388380527097/clients/rospy/src/rospy/client.py#L391), you'll see that you can specifiy a timeout. If that timeout is exceeded then an exception will be raised (I removed the parts that aren't necessary for the question)

```
def wait_for_message(topic, topic_type, timeout=None):
    """
    ...

    @param timeout: timeout time in seconds
    @type  timeout: double
    ...
    @raise ROSException: if specified timeout is exceeded
    """
```

So, just call the function like this

```
rospy.wait_for_message(my_topic, MyMessage, my_timeout)
```

and if `my_timeout` is exceeded a `ROSException` will be raised.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-07**:
No need to go to the source, just read the [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#wait_for_message).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem, using it like this:

> `rospy.wait_for_message("ar_pose_marker",AlvarMarkers)`

The problem was that I missed a `rospy.spin()` in the whole Python script, because I did not intend to create a ROS node.
However the missing rospy.spin was causing rospy not iterating through the message queues, thus waiting forever even if the topic actually publishes something.

---

Originally posted by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) with karma: 146 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1